AWS elastic beanstalk health is showing severe
I've my application running on AWS EC2, just of a sudden the site stop working. when i tried to open the site it show error:502 bad gateway.
so when i login to AWS to check the problem, I discover the elastic beanstalk health showing severe in red.
then in opened it and it shows me the message below
Application deployment failed at 2024-05-22T09:10:19Z with exit status 1 and error: Engine execution has encountered an error.
Process default has been unhealthy for 1 day (Target.FailedHealthChecks).
Please can someone help me figure out the cause of the error.
Thank you all.
Bala Toro
I tried my application code and i found everything intact. I also checked the DNS which is also ok.

you have an a load balancer issue where one of your resource instances is unhealthy.
Because you are saying its Beanstalk, its hard to say exactly the cause without more information, but I would start with the following:
Go to Elastic Load Balancer (which targets your EC2 (resources) when they scale (make more of them)
Find the unhealthy target (one of your ec2s has crashed)
Later you can see what caused the crash with Cloudwatch by going to the EC2 and checking the logs... But for now lets remove the unhealthy target and restart it.
Select the failed EC2 and remove it as a target from the ELB
Restart the EC2
Check your EC2 (ssh in or whatever you need to do to make sure its good to go)
Re-target the EC2 with the ELB
Hope this is helpful
